# Porque é que o output me esta a sair assim?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tou a tentar fazer um programa em que eu uso uma lista e esse programa de retorna 2 listas uma com os pares outra com os impares.

```
lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def par(numero):
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        return numero
def impar(numero):
    if numero % 2 != 0:
        return numero

par = list(map(par,lista))
impar = list(map(impar,lista))
print(par)
print(impar)
```

sendo que o output que ele me dá é:
    [0, None, 2, None, 4, None, 6, None, 8, None, 10]
    [None, 1, None, 3, None, 5, None, 7, None, 9, None] existe alguma forma de fazer o programa sem que esses Nones ocorram?
PS tenho de o fazer com as funcoes de ordem superior dai o uso do map

Answer (score 11):

A razão dos `None` é porque a função `map` executa as suas funções para cada elemento da lista, de forma que um retorno nessas funções é sempre necessário. Como você não retorna nada no `else` (que não existe nas suas funções), o Python assume `None` nesses casos.

Se você é obrigado a usar o `map`, uma possível solução é simplesmente remover os `None` após a chamada de `map`, talvez usando uma [compreensão](http://programacaocompython.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/listas-por-compreensao.html):

```
lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def par(numero):
    if numero % 2 == 0:
        return numero
def impar(numero):
    if numero % 2 != 0:
        return numero

par = [i for i in list(map(par,lista)) if i is not None]
impar = [i for i in list(map(impar,lista)) if i is not None]

print(par)
print(impar)
```

> Observe que ao fazer `par = ...` você altera a sua função `par`
>   previamente definida, de forma que ela não poderá mais ser utilizada.
>   Talvez fosse bom usar outro nome de variável. :)

Se por outro lado você não precisa usar o `map`, faz diretamente:

```
lista = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

par = [i for i in lista if i % 2 == 0]
impar = [i for i in lista if i % 2 != 0]

print(par)
print(impar)
```

Há ainda outra opção. Se você estiver usando [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), você pode fazer assim:

```
import numpy as np
lista = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

paridx = np.logical_not((lista % 2).astype(bool))
imparidx = (lista % 2).astype(bool)

par = lista[paridx]
impar = lista[imparidx]

print(par)
print(impar)
```

Explicando:

1. O comando `lista % 2` devolve uma lista com os restos da divisão de cada elemento por 2, o que pra sua lista ela vai devolver `[0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]`.
2. O comando `(lista % 2).astype(bool)` simplesmente converte esses 0s e 1s para valores lógicos, fazendo essa lista se tornar `[False  True False  True False  True False  True False  True False]`. Observe como basicamente ele indica `False` onde o resto da divisão por 2 é zero, e `True` onde o resto da divisão por 2 é 1. Ou seja, basicamente ele indica verdadeiro onde o número naquela posição (índice) é ímpar.
3. Por isso que o comando final é `(lista % 2).astype(bool)` para indicar os índices dos números ímpares e `np.logical_not((lista % 2).astype(bool))` (a negação lógica desses valores) para indicar os índices dos números pares.
4. Por fim, esses índices são usados diretamente para "filtrar" na lista original os itens onde o índice indica verdadeiro (`True`) - um recurso bem bacana e útil ao manipular dados: `par = lista[paridx]` e `impar = lista[imparidx]`.

Answer (score 2):

A reposta do @Luiz Vieira, está perfeita.
Junto só mais uma variante: uso de `filter` (deixa passar apenas os valores aprovados por uma função filtro).

Exemplo:

```
 lista=range(11)
 par = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0 , lista)
```